# Dynamic Visualization of Rolling 2 Dice | Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, seaborn

So, I'm trying to update the code to do 2 dice rolls instead of 1 and also plotting the sum of the 2 rolls. Every time, I get an error: ValueError: Grouper for  not 1-dimensional, for when I try to update the ranges to include the values necessary for the barplot. Need some help trying to get the plot to roll 2 dice instead of 1 and also have the plot show 2-12 on the y-axis.So far, I've attempted updating the random.randrange to add another one, and changing values and frequencies to the appropriate ranges.

```
"""Dynamically graphing frequencies of die rolls."""
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random 
import seaborn as sns
import sys

def update(frame_number, rolls, faces, frequencies):
    """Configures bar plot contents for each animation frame."""
    # roll die and update frequencies
    for i in range(rolls):
        frequencies[random.randrange(1, 7) - 1] += 1

    # reconfigure plot for updated die frequencies
    plt.cla()  # clear old contents contents of current Figure
    axes = sns.barplot(frequencies, faces, palette='bright', orient='horizontal')  # new bars
    axes.set_title(f'Die Frequencies for {sum(frequencies):,} Rolls')
    axes.set(xlabel='Frequency', ylabel='Die Value')  
    axes.set_xlim(auto=max(frequencies) * 1.10)  # scale x-axis by 10%

    # display frequency & percentage above each patch (bar)
    for bar, frequency in zip(axes.patches, frequencies):
        text_x = bar.get_width()  
        text_y = bar.get_y() + bar.get_height() / 2.0
        text = f'{frequency:,}\n{frequency / sum(frequencies):.3%}'
        axes.text(text_x, text_y, text, ha='left', va='center')

# read command-line arguments for number of frames and rolls per frame
number_of_frames = 200  
rolls_per_frame = 100  

sns.set_style('whitegrid')  # white backround with gray grid lines
figure = plt.figure('Rolling 2 Six-Sided Die')  # Figure for animation
values = list(range(1, 7))  # die faces for display on y-axis
frequencies = [0] * 6  # six-element list of die frequencies

# configure and start animation that calls function update
die_animation = animation.FuncAnimation(
    figure, update, repeat=False, frames=number_of_frames, interval=33,
    fargs=(rolls_per_frame, values, frequencies))

plt.show()  # display window
```

Comment: Posting code as image should absolutely be avoided at stackoverflow.  Can you please replace it with the code as text? [Avoid screenshots of code and errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors), [Formatting as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: @JohanC, I've updated the question to make the code as text.